# Select query data based on a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet with multiple sheets/tabs inside.
The sheet "Read_First" contains a dropdown (validate data) which let's the user select which other sheet should be used as data source (generated by a script).
On another sheet I have a query which should use the data from that selected dropdown (cell B5 in sheet Read_First).
For this I have tried the following formula

```
=query('Read_First!B5'!B:C;"select * where B is not null";1)
```

This doesn't work as it should and I am now asking for help.
How can I use the selected sheet name from the dropdown in Read_First!B5 as the query data B:C command?

Comment: Have you checked the [Reading data](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#reading_data) in Apps Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found out about this solution which works as expected for me:

```
=query(INDIRECT(Read_First!B5&"!B:C");"select * where B is not null";1)
```

Thanks @Chemiadel for the hint

Answer (score 0):

i think you request should look something like that

```
=query(Read_First!B:C,"select * where B=("&Read_First!B5&")",-1)
```

More about QUERY function

[QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

Comment: No, because the sheet name is selected in Read_First!B5 but the query(data,...) command should use the selected sheet for range B:C.